# probability density function, solve for c

Tags: probability

For the probability density function

> $$ f(x)=c \frac{x}{x^2 + 1}  \quad \rm{for} \quad 0\leq x \leq 2 $$

a) Find $c$.

b) find $E(X)$ and $VAR(X)$

To find $c$, you set the integral equal to $1$. So 1 = $c$ $\ln(x^2+1)\over 2$ from $0$ to $2$ and I solved for $c = 1.24$. Is this correct?

Can someone help on part b?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: So to find $E(X)$ I would have to take the integral from 0 to 2 of $x^2\over x^2+1$, right? I'm not sure how to integrate something of this type.

Answer (score 1):

For $\mathbb{E}(X)$ we have that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X) &= c\int_{0}^2\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}dx \\
&= c\int_{0}^2\frac{x^2+1-1}{x^2+1}dx \\
&= 2c- c\int_{0}^2\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx\\
&= 2c- c(\arctan(2)-\arctan(0)).
\end{align}
The variance is given by
$$
\text{var}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2)-\left(\mathbb{E}(X)\right)^2.
$$
Let us calculate $\mathbb{E}(X^2)$. We have that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X^2) &= c\int_{0}^2\frac{x^3}{x^2+1}dx.
\end{align}
Now,
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^2\frac{x^3}{x^2+1}dx&= \int_{0}^2x\frac{x^2-1+1}{x^2+1}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^2xdx-\int_0^2\frac{x}{x^2+1}dx,
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\int_0^2\frac{x}{x^2+1}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^2\frac{1}{x^2+1}d(x^2) = \frac{1}{2}\left.\ln(x^2+1)\right|_0^2 = \frac{1}{2}\ln5.
\end{align}
From here, I believe that you will succeed to continue...

Comment: So $Var(X)$ = $E(X^2) - E(X)$. So we need to calculate $E(X^2)$.

$$c\int_{0}^2 \frac{x^3}{x^2 + 1}$$

But is there a trick to get that $x^3$ off the top?

Comment: What happens to the c's for variance? Would I do the same thing that you did for $E(X)$?

Comment: Of course! I just wrote the results of the integrals which you will need to compute in the calculation of the variance.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just confused as to where the $2c - c$ came from

Comment: Does E(X) = 1.1? Also for Variance when you split it up into 2 integrals, does each integral get its own c? I'm still confused as to where 2c - c came from when solving for E(X)?